# JSF show TextFields in a row in a Datatable when a button is clicked from a column in the same row,

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

Folks,

This is my second day working with JSF, so kindly bear with me if my questions are not very clear
I'll try to be clear as much as possible.

From the attached screen, you can see a table with the
first row being blank and from the second row you have table entries.

What I would like to do is, I want to use the first row of the table as an entry
where I can enter values for ID, Name and Value.

One I click "Save" button, the row should be added to the database and it
should be fetched and displayed. I dont have any problem with the database part.

My Questions are: (Pleae provide code snipets when you provide the solution)

1) I need to show the Textfields for (ID, Name and Value) once I click
   the "Edit" button for the rows with values and once I click the "Edit"
   button I need to Enable the "Save" button which is disabled when the
   Table is loaded, so that I can do modifications, right now it looks like a label.

After making the changes to the TextField when I hit the
save button I need to disable it.

I would like the row to be like the first row of the Table 
but with values in it to edit it. 
How to achieve that ?

2) Is it possible to refer to id of the button and check whether it is
   enabled or disabled to render the Textfields(ID, Name and Value) ?

Here is the column code for the table

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Value" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.value}" />
    <h:inputText id="value" value="#{dataItem.value}" rendered="#{dataItem.value == null}"/>
</h:column>
```

I do not render the  when i have the data for a particular row,
this is done so that i display either outputText or inputText at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code for such cases can take a lot of time. We have used a number of similar screen so here are some hints with psuedocode...

```
BackingBean {
    // take a current variable to keep selected row
    DataItem current;
    // list of dataitems to show in grid 
    List<DataItem> listOfItems;

    // Use ActionListener to set current
    editActionListener(ActionEvent e){
        current = read via actionevent.getAttribute()
    }
    // Use save to save the data, reload the table, disable the button
    saveAction(){
        ManagerBean.save(current);
        reload listOfItems;
        current = null;
        disable save;
    }
}
```

Now in the xhtml show the values from current:

```
<table component>
<row>
    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.current.id}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.current.name}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{backingBean.current.value}" />
</row>
<loop across "#{backingBean.listofItems}" with "item" variable>
    <row>
        <h:inputText value="#{item.id}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{item.name}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
        <h:commandButton text="Edit" 
                    actionListener="#{backingBean.editActionListener}" />
        <h:commandButton text="Save" actionListener="#{backingBean.saveActionListener}"
                    action="#{backingBean.saveAction}" />
    </row>
</endloop>
</table component>
```